# Python plot adding one color and marker legend to a multicolumn dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, matplotlib

I have bigdataframe of many columns. But they are categorized into three categories.

```
bigdf.columns = 

[cat1_x1,cat1_y1,cat1_x2,cat1_y2,cat2_x1,cat2_y1,cat2_x2 ,cat3_y2,cat3_x1,cat3_y1,cat3_x2,cat3_y2]
```

I am plotting the data of all category columns. I want to represent the data of a category column using same color and marker.

My present code:

```
plt.plot(bigdf[[cat1_x1,cat1_x2]],bigdf[[cat1_y1,cat1_y2]],'-c*',markerfacecolor='none',label='Cat1')
plt.plot(bigdf[[cat2_x1,cat2_x2]],bigdf[[cat2_y1,cat2_y2]],'-go',markerfacecolor='none',label='cat2')
plt.plot(bigdf[[cat3_x1,cat3_x2]],bigdf[[cat3_y1,cat3_y2]],'-bs',markerfacecolor='none',label='cat2')
plt.ylabel("Module %s"%(ylbl))  ## result_df.dtypes , shunt resistance ($\Omega$)
plt.xlabel("Irradiance (W/m$^2$)")
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.15, right=0.99, top=0.95, bottom=0.19)
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.ylim([0,ylim_mod])
plt.show()
```

My present output:

[image]

Legend is big because the df has many columns. How to modify legend to show three labels only?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest would be to draw all the plots separately, and only provide a label to the first of every category.

Here's an adapted version of the code. I introduced two loops which hopefully makes the code easier to read and maintain:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

cat1_x1,cat1_y1,cat1_x2,cat1_y2,cat2_x1,cat2_y1,cat2_x2,cat2_y2,cat3_x1,cat3_y1,cat3_x2,cat3_y2 =\
    'cat1_x1,cat1_y1,cat1_x2,cat1_y2,cat2_x1,cat2_y1,cat2_x2,cat2_y2,cat3_x1,cat3_y1,cat3_x2,cat3_y2'.split(',')
bigdf = pd.DataFrame(columns=[cat1_x1,cat1_y1,cat1_x2,cat1_y2,cat2_x1,cat2_y1,cat2_x2,cat2_y2,cat3_x1,cat3_y1,cat3_x2,cat3_y2])

cats = [[[f'cat{i}_x{j}', f'cat{i}_y{j}'] for j in range(1, 3)] for i in range(1, 4)]
labels = ['Cat 1', 'Cat 2', 'Cat 3']
styles = ['-c*', '-go', '-bs']
for cat, label, style in zip(cats, labels, styles):
    for ind, cxy in enumerate(cat):
        plt.plot(bigdf[cxy[0]], bigdf[cxy[1]], style, markerfacecolor='none', label=label if ind == 0 else None)
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.15, right=0.99, top=0.95, bottom=0.19)
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.show()
```

[image: sample plot]

Comment: Was this answer helpful?